# Question regarding hexadecimal multiplication in C using datatype int64_t

Tags: c

When I try to carry out hex multiplication of 16 bits by 16bits using the datatype int64_t, the result displayed is restricted to 32 bits, and a 33rd bit, if present is never displayed, although I am defining the operands as well as result to be 64 bits in length.

Here is the simple code I am using:

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include <stdint.h>  

int main()  
{  
   int64_t a, b, r;  
   a = 0xabcd;  
   b = 0xdbca;  
   r = a * b * 3;  
   printf("%x", r);  
   return 0;  
}
```

Result printed out is : `ba7fcc46`

Expected Result is : `1ba7fcc46`

Kindly help me out here.

Comment: I think that the problem is that %x is the wrong printf modifier for 64-bit values, but I don't know the correct one.  Anyone know this?

Comment: If you're multiplying 2 16-bit values, the result fits in 32 bits. There is no need for a larger type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popular solution is to use `%llx` for your `printf` format. `ll` means `long long` (64-bit long on virtually all systems), although this is not portable.

The portable (however, less legible) solution,  is to use @anatolyg's answer, reprinted here:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
// ...
printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", r);
```

Comment: This would have been a good answer if you had included the caveats that it's not a conforming solution and it has portability issues. It's a common solution and we all use it at times, but it is technically the wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was unaware of the `PRIx64` macro mentioned in other answers. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The format specifier for `int64_t` depends on platform (`%I64x` on Windows, `%llx` on any other platform, YMMV). So there is a macro you can use that looks ugly but will work on any system:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
...
printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", r);
```

If you don't mind your code not working on Windows, you can just use `%llx`.

---

(Edited; the name of the macro was wrong)

Comment: Good answer. I made the mistake of taking a coffee break ... broke the SO rules ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

what we do is this

```
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
printf("%lx\n", r);
#else
printf("%llx\n", r);
#endif
```

This keeps the type correct for both 64 bit and 32 bit machines.
BTW this is for gcc/g++.  Not sure if it's portable

Comment: It's not, and there's a correct portable way to do it with the `PRIx64` macro.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are only a few ways for a conforming program to specifically print an `int64_t`, and they all look about like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void f(int64_t x) {
  printf("Value %30" PRId64 "\n", x);
}

int main(void) {
  f((int64_t)1000000000 * 1000000000);
  return 0;
}
```